# Long-term visit visa for UAE: after which date should I leave?

Tags: visas, dubai

I applied for a 90-day visa and got a long-term visit, single-entry tourist visa. The date given is 09-March-2015, and it's valid until 07-May-2015.

My agent says the 7th is the latest date I can travel to Dubai; once I enter I need to count 90 days. I entered on the 10th of March.

Is it true, or where can I get it checked?

Can I stay for another month, or do I need to leave before the 7th of May?

Comment: I would highly doubt the claim made by your agent, about you being able to enter on the last day of your visa validity and to stay for a term of 90 days.

Comment: @edocetirwi Quite a few countries do actually issue visas like this: the validity date states when the visa must be *used* by, and the clock on the 90 days *in the country* only starts ticking when you enter the country.

Comment: @jpatokal Good to kow. Thnx.

Comment: @edocetirwi One such country is the USA.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can stay longer (up to 90 days!).  This is how the visa works.

They put a deadline on when you can enter, for a number a reasons - knowledge of numbers, validity of passport, relations between them and your country, whatever - but there's a final date on which you can enter.  That's the May 7th.

Once you arrive, your visa 'begins'.  It'll run for 90 days from when you arrive. Note the distinction - it's not three months, but 90 days, be careful when calculating.

If you'd like a slightly more official source than me, [Emirates lists the visas](http://www.emirates.com/au/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/prearranged_uae_visas.aspx) and notes "  90 days from arrival date" as well.

Answer (score 3):

After you entered UAE, you can check the validity [here](https://www.ednrd.ae/portal/pls/portal/INIMM_DB.DBPK_VISAVALIDITY.Query_VisaValidity).